# Getting error:-"The app can take some time to load. You can wait, try closing the app and opening it again, or clear your settings and log in again."

Tags: integration, developer-edition

When integrating outlook(using outlook web app) to salesforce(free dev edition)[image: The page is getting stuck on this:-]".

Already referenced all help articles with error.
Is i am missing something apart from Trailhead's Outlook Integration module

Answer (score 0):

Since the Salesforce for Outlook add-in uses Internet Explorer, it's also affected by internet explorer security policies. Some articles I've found suggest that the Salesforce for Outlook add-in needs to run in Protected mode. So try these settings:

- Enable Protected mode for Internet Zone
- Enable Protected mode for Restricted Zone
- Make sure *.salesforce.com is not included in trusted sites list. (Trusted sites are not run in Protected mode)

You can search the start menu for Internet Options, then go to the Security tab to find these settings.

I am also experiencing this issue, but only when signing into Production orgs, I can sign into Sandbox orgs just fine and switch in between emails without re-entering my credentials.

Comment: See source: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000eumjQAA